# How to make text and carousel using d-flex responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have the following code to display carousel and text side-by-side and it is working fine in browser. However in mobile responsive, the text is not appearing and only carousel is showing. I am new to CSS. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

CSS:

```
.hero-wrap .author-info, .hero-wrap .author-image { width: 100%; }
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .hero-wrap .author-info, .hero-wrap .author-image { width: 50%; } 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center js-fullheight">
   <div class="author-image text img d-flex">
   // carousel
   </div>
   <div class="author-info text p-3 p-md-5">
   // text
   </div>
</div>
```

The website is live at [www.rrkastro.com](http://www.rrkastro.com) and above code is in homepage.

Comment: Hello. What markup do you want to see?

Comment: the text contained in <div> with class="author-info" is not visible in mobile. Thanks

Comment: But then the height of the text becomes like the height of the slider. It doesn't look very nice. Something from the text will have to be excluded for mobile display.

Comment: Got it. Thank you @s.kuznetsov . I tweaked by creating a duplicate section and setting its visibility to block for mobile display. Though it is not right approach, I will wait for a proper solution. Thanks again.